# Set /a not working as 2 / 2

Tags: batch-file

I couldn't get %difference_two% to work It can find %difference_one% as 2 but when I make it divide 2 by 2 it doesn't display as anything.
Use the numbers 2,5,10,17,26
To get what I need.

```
@echo off
color 0a
title Solver

:numbers
cls
set /p first=First: 
set /p second=Second: 
set /p third=Third: 
set /p fourth=Fourth: 
set /p fifth=Fifth: 
goto solve

:solve
cls
set /a second_minus_first= %second% - %first%
set /a third_minus_second= %third% - %second%
if %third_minus_second%==%second_minus_first% (
goto s
) else (
goto d
)

:d
cls
set /a fourth_minus_third= %fourth% - %third%
set /a difference= %third_minus_second% - %second_minus_first%
set /a difference_one= %fourth_minus_third% - %third_minus_second%
if %difference%==%difference_one% (
set /a difference_two= %difference_one% / 2
set /a thing= %first% - %difference_two%
cls
echo %difference_two%n Squared + %thing%
pause >nul
goto numbers
) else (
goto wrong
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0a
title Solver

:numbers
cls
set /p first=First: 
set /p second=Second: 
set /p third=Third: 
set /p fourth=Fourth: 
set /p fifth=Fifth: 
goto solve

:solve
cls
set /a second_minus_first= %second% - %first%
set /a third_minus_second= %third% - %second%
if %third_minus_second%==%second_minus_first% (
goto s
) else (
goto d
)

:d
cls
set /a fourth_minus_third= %fourth% - %third%
set /a difference= %third_minus_second% - %second_minus_first%
set /a difference_one= %fourth_minus_third% - %third_minus_second%
if %difference%==%difference_one% (
set /a difference_two= !difference_one! / 2
set /a thing= !first! - !difference_two!
cls
echo !difference_two!n Squared + !thing!
pause >nul
goto numbers
) else (
goto wrong
)
```

In batch, commands in a code block (between `( )`) are interpreted as on the same line, so you need to use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and use `!` instead of `%` inside them.

Comment: Thanks, Could you tell me what you did differently so i can know for later.

Comment: @Joseph added explanation. I also suggest looking [here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thanks, i sort of get it and do you know what I'm doing on batch? Just as a challenge?

Comment: @Joseph solving `n^2+1` I guess?

Comment: Yes I'm doing quadratic equations so I can cheat on my maths. Such a weird way to do homework but it works.

Comment: @Joseph frankly, I don't care how/if you cheat on your homework, but remember that batch won't save you on your exams.

Comment: @Joseph or should I call you Sir Disco?

Comment: Don't care really I use SirDisco as my gamertag. And no batch wont save me on my exams I can do this anyway in my head I just wanted a bit of fun.